# can anyone help me get this button onclick to work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button

I am trying to make an online message board as a university project and i would like it to redirect the user to another page when they click on the username of the person who sent the message. The username is pulled from a database using sql and then implemented into html as a button using c#. The problem is that this button will not respond to its onclick.

here is my server side c# code which reads the message database then converts it to html

```
while (R.Read()){
     messageIndex = messageIndex + "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" id=\"msg" 
     + R["MessageID"] + "\"name =\"msg" + R["MessageID"] + "\" 
     runat=\"server\"  onServerClick=\"btnAccountClick\" value=\"" + 
     R["username"]  + "\"/></input></td>";

     messageIndex = messageIndex + "<td>:   " + R["message"] + "</td> 
     </tr>";};
sqlCon.Close();
parData.InnerHtml = "<table>" + messageIndex + "</table>";
```

here is the html code which displays "pardata"

```
<div runat="server" >
        <span id="parData" runat="server"></span>
</div>
```

and here is the onserverclick function to redirect the page

```
protected void btnAccountClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("userInfo.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: If all you are doing is a redirect, it's usually recommended to just prevent the extra call and go to the page directly via javascript.

That way, you are not necessarily sending things like viewstate to the page

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating HTML elements not webform controls. If you want to use the onServerClick method you will need to create a new button control and define the properties before it is rendered on the client side. See [Add asp:Button from codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397920) for help.